# My function isn't returning

Tags: javascript, canvas, return

Ehllo! My function isn't returning (exiting) when conditions are met.

```
var arrowReady = false;
var arrowImage = new Image();
var deg = 0;
arrowImage.onload = function () {
    arrowReady = true;
    function moveArrow() {
        setInterval(function() {
            ctx1.save();
            deg++;
            ctx1.rotate(deg * Math.PI / 180);
            // Here is  ^  the amount of degrees it turns.
            ctx1.clearRect(300, 200, 52, 310);
            ctx1.drawImage(arrowImage, 300, 100, 42, 300);
            ctx1.restore();
        }, 100);

        if (deg == 40) return;

    }
}
```

From my understanding, when deg = 40, the function should stop. But, it's not. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to stop the function in setInterval when `deg == 40`?

Comment: Yes, that is the plan. I got it figured out, @Alex Mcp's answer worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky javascript going on here. `moveArrow` is only called once on document load. returning or not will not stop your interval from running.

You need to save a reference to the interval:

```
var interval = setInterval(...
```

And then from WITHIN the anonymous `setInterval` function, when `deg ==40` you will want to `clearInterval(interval)` to stop it from running.

Try this:

```
var arrowReady = false;
var arrowImage = new Image();
var deg = 0;
arrowImage.onload = function () {
    arrowReady = true;
    function moveArrow() {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (deg == 40) {
              clearInterval(interval);
              return;
            }
            ctx1.save();
            deg++;
            ctx1.rotate(deg * Math.PI / 180);
            // Here is  ^  the amount of degrees it turns.
            ctx1.clearRect(300, 200, 52, 310);
            ctx1.drawImage(arrowImage, 300, 100, 42, 300);
            ctx1.restore();
        }, 100);

    }
}
```

Comment: Will the closure magic work in this case? That would require `interval` being captured as a reference, cause I believe it's not initialized before `setInterval` returns.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a JavaScript programmer but don't you need to specify a value to return

EXAMPLE `if (deg == 40) return deg;`

Comment: No, that's not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what that last conditional is even supposed to do.  There's nothing after it, so the function is going to stop execution there anyway.  Why does it matter if `deg == 40` if that's where the function call ends no matter what?

More to the point, I'm sure, is the fact that the function in question doesn't actually *change* the value of `deg`.  So `deg` will never equal `40` on that line.  What you're doing is queuing up another function to run at a later time (100 ms?).  After that function is queued up, the control *immediately* goes to the `if` statement (before that other function runs).

So `deg` is being modified, in a completely different function scope, after the `if` statement executes.